# Whitespace in xsl:text elements

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When running this with Saxon 9.8, I get following result:

```
1
        2
```

When running this with MSXML 6.0, the whitespace is stripped and I get:

`1 2`

What is the correct behavior? Is the whitespace here supposed to be stripped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to do with whitespace striping in the XSLT document. According to the [W3C specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#strip) (for XSLT 1.0, which is what MSXML uses)

> A text node is preserved if any of the following apply:
>
> The element name of the parent of the text node is in the set of
>   whitespace-preserving element names.
>
> The text node contains at least one non-whitespace character. As in
>   XML, a whitespace character is #x20, #x9, #xD or #xA.
>
> An ancestor element of the text node has an xml:space attribute with a
>   value of preserve, and no closer ancestor element has xml:space with a
>   value of default.

It then says "*For stylesheets, the set of whitespace-preserving element names consists of just xsl:text.*"

So, is looks like MSXML is not following the specification.

However, if you add `xml:space="preserve"` to the `xsl:text` in question, you might find it does work in MSXML

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
  <xsl:text xml:space="preserve">
  </xsl:text>
  <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct behaviour is as you see it from Saxon.

There's some history here and I don't remember the full details, but MSXML has a nasty habit of stripping whitespace text nodes within the parser itself. If the XML parser strips out the whitespace text nodes, then they never get as far as the XSLT processor, so it makes no difference whether that conforms to all the XSLT rules or not.

I'm pretty sure there are options in MSXML to control this behaviour, so check exactly how you are invoking the MSXML parser and change the options if necessary.